# why the same program slower in linux 2.6.32 than 2.6.18?

Tags: c, linux, x86, 64-bit, cpu

I wrote a program, which is so simple.

```
void do_test() {
    const char *s = "http://";
    int i = 0;
    for(; i<100000; ++i) {
        const char *p = s;
        while(*p != '/') {
            ++p;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i<100; ++i) {
       do_test();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

run this code 100 times,will lead the difference.it costs 1.29s in my 64 bit server with kernel linux 2.6.32, but it just costs 1.23s in my 32 bit server with kernel 2.6.18.

Comment: Is it reliably slower, that is, it's always about 60 ms slower?

Comment: In the title you are comparing a program on two kernel versions, but in the question you are comparing a program on two different machines with two different kernel versions.

Comment: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz. the cpu is the same.

Comment: Could it be that your slower machine is just tired and needs some coffee as a pick-me-up?

Comment: Why not compile as 32-bit and compare?

Answer (score 2):

Since the hardware is different, the difference in performance might have (and very probably has) nothing to do with the kernel.

Moreover, I would think of compiler optimizations, CPU architecture, etc. well before blaming the kernel...

Comment: Always blame the kernel... never blame yourself! ;-)

Comment: so would you give me some suggetions to find the reason?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Why blame yourself if you can blame a compiler bug, language defect, poor library implementation or high air pressure?

Answer (score 1):

Even if two computers have the same specs the hardware may not be strictly identical, nanoscopic differences during the manufacturing of the processors could lead to this small difference (~1%)

Comment: The timings are ~5% different. Thermal environment could have a larger impact. Since the processor base frequency and microarchitecture are the same, manufacturing variation would only affect turboboosting. Even different cores within the same chip could have detectable differences.